How consume messages indefinitely in RabbitMQ using amqpblig?
I did a native a simple approach using ampqlib following RabbitMQ official documentation to consume messages indefinitely:
After a couple days suffering, my manager explained it was a really silly error: setInterval was being called repeatedly and triggering consumeMessage several times, causing an overflow.
Considering that setInterval returns an object, we just have to verify if it already exists:
const ampq = require('ampqlib');
const JSON = require('JSON');
const winston = require('winston');

let connection = null;

const workerFunction = async (mesage) => {
  // A lot of work not requried for the example
  return result_message;
};

const createConnection = async () => {
  if (connection !== null) {
    // Winston logger setup hidden to simplify example
    logger.info('createConnection: connection already created');
    return connection;
  }

  connection = await amqp.connect({
    hostname: HOSTNAME,
    port: RABBITMQ_PORT,
    username: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER,
    password: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS,
    vhost: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST,
  });

  logger.info('createConnection: connection created');
  return connection;
}

const sendMessage = async (message) => {

  try {
    connection = await createConnection();
    const channel = await connection.createChannel();
    await channel.assertQueue('consumer', { durable: true });

    const msg = JSON.stringify(message, null, 4);
    channel.sendToQueue('consumer', Buffer.from(msg));
    await channel.close();
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error('sendMessage', e);
  }
};

const consumeMessage = async (message) => {
  try{
    logger.info('consumeMessage', message);

    const connection = await createConnection();
    const channel = await connection.createChannel();
    await channel.assertQueue('worker', { durable: true });

    await channel.consume(
      'worker',
      await workerFunction(message),
      { noAck: false }
    );
    logger.info('consumeMessage', message);
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error('consumeMessage', error);
  }
}

const consumeMessages = () => {
  const gson = JSON.parse(message.content.toString());

  setInterval(async () => {
    await consumeMessage();
  }, 200);
};

And finally to invoke it at the Express.js server:
consumeMessages.catch(logger.error);
    

After a couple days running, it always caused an overflow.
Any ideas why it could be causing it?

After a couple days suffering, my manager explained it was a really silly error: setInterval was being called repeatedly and triggering consumeMessage several times, causing an overflow.
Considering that setInterval returns an object, we just have to verify if it already exists:
const ampq = require('ampqlib');
const JSON = require('JSON');
const winston = require('winston');

let connection = null;
let interval = null;

const workerFunction = async (mesage) => {
  // A lot of work not requried for the example
  return result_message;
};

const createConnection = async () => {
  if (connection !== null) {
     // Winston logger setup hidden to simplify example
     logger.info('createConnection: connection already created');
     return connection;
   }

  connection = await amqp.connect({
    hostname: HOSTNAME,
    port: RABBITMQ_PORT,
    username: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER,
    password: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS,
    vhost: RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST,
  });

  logger.info('createConnection: connection created');
  return connection;
}

const sendMessage = async (message) => {

  try {
    connection = await createConnection();
    const channel = await connection.createChannel();
    await channel.assertQueue('consumer', { durable: true });

    const msg = JSON.stringify(message, null, 4);
    channel.sendToQueue('consumer', Buffer.from(msg));
    await channel.close();
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error('sendMessage', e);
  }
};

const consumeMessage = async (message) => {
  try{
    logger.info('consumeMessage', message);

    const connection = await createConnection();
    const channel = await connection.createChannel();
    await channel.assertQueue('worker', { durable: true });

    await channel.consume(
      'worker',
      await workerFunction(message),
      { noAck: false }
    );
    logger.info('consumeMessage: message processed.', message);
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error('consumeMessage', error);
  }
}

const consumeMessages = () => {
  // FIXME: Check if repater was already created
  if (interval === null) return;

  const gson = JSON.parse(message.content.toString());

  interval = setInterval(async () => await consumeMessage(), 200);
};

